# Excel VBA- Average all numeric cells in a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro that iterates over all used cells in a worksheet and return the average.
The eventual goal is to get the average value of the numbers in each worksheet, and produce a line graph with the averages.

I'm having difficulty understanding how to do this.  My strategy right now (which is probably sub-optimal) involves a) finding the first row with numeric data; b) finding the first column with numeric data; c) finding the last row with numeric data; d) finding the last column with numeric data; d) creating a range over those cells; e) averaging the range

Here's my current code

```
Sub AverageAllNumbers()
     Dim fRow As Long
     Dim fColumn As Long
     Dim lRow As Long
     Dim lColumn As Long
     Dim dblAverage As Long
     Dim averageRange As Range

    fRow = Cells.Find(What:=Number, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row
    fColumn = Cells.Find(What:=Number, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    lRow = Cells.Find(What:=Number, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lColumn = Cells.Find(What:=Number, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    averageRange = Range(Cells(fRow, fColumn), Cells(lRow, lColumn))

    dblAverage = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(averageRange)
    MsgBox dblAverage

End Sub
```

Almost nothing works-- 'lColumn' produces 16384, and fRow and fColumn produces 1, which is not even a used cell in my spreadsheet.

What's going on?

Comment: @pnuts that was already mentioned in a deleted answer. A simple alternative maybe just `Msgbox application.average(cells)` which i think only applies to the used range.

Comment: why not use `=average(a:xfd)` or `application.worksheetfunction.average(a:xfd)`

Comment: @lori_m and Dean have viable solutions. But I'd like to see an answer that explains why the `Cells.Find` calls work for lRow and not the others.

Comment: Jack - `Number` is not defined, try instead `What:="*"` and `Set AverageRange = ...`

Comment: @pnuts - i meant that only the used range is taken into account for the calculation so referencing the whole worksheet is feasible. This is not the case for other functions such as SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: It looks like using `What:=Number` includes blank cells as numbers... sometimes.  For lColumn, the _address_ being selected on a worksheet I made is "XFD1048576", and the _address_ being selected for lRow is "XFD12".  I'm not sure **at all** why that is happening.  I had no data past cell L11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the `Worksheet.UsedRange` Property?

```
Sub AverageAll()
    Dim average As Double
    Dim averageRange As Range

    ' Set averageRange to UsedRange; no need to find it ourselves.
    Set averageRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    average = Application.WorksheetFunction.average(averageRange)
    MsgBox average
End Sub
```

It worked for me in a test case, albeit a trivial one.

Answer (score 2):

Should be a one-liner:

```
Sub SheetAverage()
    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
End Sub
```